# Upper bound for smallest eigenvalue for the matrix $\mathbf{S} (\mathbf{S}^{T} \mathbf{S} + \lambda \mathbf{A})^{-2} \mathbf{S}^{T}$

Tags: inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My book claims that the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix

$$\mathbf{S} (\mathbf{S}^{T} \mathbf{S} + \lambda \mathbf{A})^{-2} \mathbf{S}^{T},$$

where $\mathbf{S}$ is an $n \times k $ matrix and $\mathbf{A}$ is a $k \times k$ positive semi-definite matrix and $\lambda>0$, is proportional to $1/\lambda$. Could you please provide an argument for this? It's not immediately obvious to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The thing that strikes me as odd about this assertion is that - if true - it implies that the eigenvalues must diverge as $\lambda \rightarrow 0$, i.e. that the eigenvalues/vectors of the matrix ${\bf S}{({\bf S}^T{\bf S})}^{-2}{\bf S}^T$ do not exist. I don't think that's true in general. Do we have any other information or restrictions on these matrices?

Comment: For instance, there's nothing in the statement of the problem that prevents having $n = k$ and ${\bf S} = {\bf I}$, where ${\bf I}$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: @JohnBarber Thank you for your comments. Perhaps it will help to know that $\mathbf{A}$ can be taken to be positive definite, that is, with strictly positive eigenvalues.

Comment: If that's the only restriction, then the assertion is false. Counterexample: Take $n = k$ and ${\bf S} = {\bf I}$ the identity matrix. Then it's pretty straightforward to show that if an eigenvalue of ${\bf A}$ is $\alpha$, then $1/{(1 + \lambda\alpha)}^2$ is an eigenvalue of ${\bf S}{({\bf S}^T {\bf S} + \lambda {\bf A})}^{-2} {\bf S}^T$. The latter expression is *not* proportional to $1/\lambda$. Is there some additional context? For example, is this by any chance from (say) a physics text?

Comment: @JohnBarber Could they mean the largest eigenvalue? I can see what they want to do is establish a bound on the expression $\mathbf{b}^{T} \mathbf{S} (\mathbf{S}^{T} \mathbf{S} + \lambda \mathbf{A})^{-2} \mathbf{S}^{T} \mathbf{b}$ off the form $C \mathbf{b}^{T} \mathbf{b}$ for some $C>0$.

Comment: Is the context of this assertion is some kind of generalized Ridge regression?

Comment: @V.Vancak Yes, exactly.